# Mapbox missing element from OSM

Tags: label, mapbox

I'm using mapbox studio to style a map that I want to use.

Map that I'm playing with at the moment: 
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/jailby/cin8wzt270008adnp6oqve9f6.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamFpbGJ5IiwiYSI6ImNpbjh3YXA1bDFqOGh1ZGtzcXlrajV3cGQifQ.8c78IvXfNkZDU56XbQ3f-Q#17.234093841967688/28.058669659076003/-82.41559446189183/0

I noticed that multiple elements were missing from the map I'm styling.

The abbreviation of building name withing their label is missing:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/103706491

Bollards are missing as well
http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/893145296

So, I was wondering if anyone know why these elements are left out and how to add them?

I understood that if something is missing it is possible to create a new layer and select the corresponding element and add it to the current style. However I was unable to do so for this two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import the OSM data yourself. First query and export what you want using [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) and then add it as a new layer within Studio. Heres a [tutorial that walks you through the process](https://www.mapbox.com/help/overpass-turbo/).

Comment: That's great I was able to get the bollards. However, I am having difficulties to get the abbreviation for buildings.

Comment: You should be using a different tag for the abbreviation in OSM. Heres [naming on OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Names#Abbreviation_.28don.27t_do_it.29) which says not to use abbreviations. Maybe consider using `short_name=*` instead?

Comment: Sorry I think I meant acronym and not abbreviation. The names are formated as follow `Building name (BN)` but in the map on ly the part `Building name` is present. I will create a separate issue and accept your answer since it solve my initial problem. Thank you for your help.